# could not save application settings java.io.EOFEexception in rubymine

Tags: java, exception, rubymine, rubymine-7

Hi am facing this issue when I open rubymine

> could not save application settings java.io.EOFEexception

[image]

I don't know why its coming my rubymine version is 7.0.1
Please help me out how to overcome with this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not alone.  Something is going wrong with RubyMine + Settings, even on MacOS. Also occurs on 7.1.2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16662 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16759